# Parsing flags/arguments from a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, flags

I'm building a "terminal-thingy" in javascript. The idea is that each command is a separate .js file, in AMD format, and everything is loaded with requirejs.

I want the commands to be called like:

```
command -s "string u-l: extra" -g http://domain.com/random.txt -r -a --test fixed
```

and that would then translate into something like:

```
command({'-s': 'string u-l: extra', '-g': 'http://domain.com/random.txt', '-r': true, '-a': true, '--test': 'fixed'});
```

But this is where I get stuck, I've tried running different scenarios in my head, but I cant find any good answer, but I can come up with conflicts:

- split() - what if there is some extra spaces, that breaks everything
- regex - regex relies on getting similar string every time, what if I want to have something like "wget http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"?
- defining rules in the command itself - still need to figure out parsing
- piping - what if I want to have piping, I have to figure out how to not break on wrong pipes, i.e: "command -s 'random | pipe' | command2 asd"

Any ideas/advices would be appreciated, I'm stuck with this.

Answer (score -1):

Would things be easier if you separated :

- parsing (with a special purpose lib like https://github.com/jfd/optparse-js ?)
- translating the parsed input into a list of required modules (you would have to define a mapping between arguments and command modules, if I understand correctly)
- requiring the said modules, and then passing the relevant arguments to each module ?